# How to calculate the average of multiple standard deviations in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics, standard-deviation

I am trying to figure out how to calculate the standard deviation of a dataset when I have a couple of standard deviations. Let's just look at this MWE:

```
set.seed(1234)
dummy_data <- data.frame(
  "col_1" = sample(1:7, size = 10, replace = TRUE),
  "col_2" = sample(1:7, size = 10, replace = TRUE),
  "col_3" = sample(1:7, size = 10, replace = TRUE),  
  "col_4" = sample(1:7, size = 10, replace = TRUE)
)
```

Now since I know all the data points I can calculate the total standard deviation as follows:

```
> sd(as.matrix(dummy_data))
[1] 1.727604
```

But the real data that I have at hand is the following:

```
> dplyr::summarise_all(dummy_data, sd)
     col_1    col_2   col_3    col_4
1 1.837873 1.873796 1.37032 1.888562
```

If I follow the usual method of calculating the average of multiple standard deviations with similar sample sizes, I would apply the following:

```
sds <- dplyr::summarise_all(dummy_data, sd)
vars <- sds^2
mean_sd <- sqrt(sum(vars) / (length(vars) - 1))

> mean_sd
[1] 2.027588
```

which is not the same! Now I have tried without the minus one:

```
> sqrt(sum(vars) / (length(vars)))
[1] 1.755942
```

which does not solve the problem. I have tried defining an own standard deviation function like this:

```
own_sd <- function(x) {
  sqrt(sum((x - mean(x))^2) / length(x))
}
```

to eliminate the `x - 1` in the `dplyr::summarise_all()` step, and then average according to the step above:

```
> sqrt(sum(dplyr::summarise_all(dummy_data, own_sd)^2) / 3)
[1] 1.923538
> sqrt(sum(dplyr::summarise_all(dummy_data, own_sd)^2) / 4)
[1] 1.665833
```

But all seem to give a different result than the `sd(as.matrix())` method. What is going wrong here?

Comment: Also take a look here, for if you happen to have the group means as well: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2971315/how-do-i-combine-standard-deviations-of-two-groups

Comment: Thank you for that link! Will read into it and make work of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't calculate a global SD from only knowing group SDs. For example:

```
x1 = 1:5
x2 = 11:15
x3 = 101:105

## all the SDs are equal
(sd1 = sd(x1))
#[1] 1.581139
(sd2 = sd(x2))
#[1] 1.581139
(sd3 = sd(x3))
#[1] 1.581139

## however, combining the groups in pairs give very different results
sd(c(x1, x2))
# [1] 5.477226

sd(c(x1, x3))
# [1] 52.72571
```

This demonstrates that even if the sample sizes are identical, knowing the standard deviation of two groups does not help you calculate the standard deviation of those groups combined.

As per Merijn van Tilborg's comment, if you know the group sizes and the group means, the calculation is possible [as shown here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2971315/32504).

Comment: Thank you very much for your time! What does the average SD that is calculated via `sqrt(sum(sd^2) / (n - 1))` tell you then? What is that used for, if not the global standard deviation?

Comment: I've never heard of that, it seems useless to me. Where did you find it?

Comment: Maybe it would be meaningful if all the variables have the same mean and the same sample size? Seems like some big assumptions there.

Comment: Well I think that it was just my lack of knowledge on this subject. I think I searched using the wrong terms, but I found the `wtd.stats` methods in the package `Hmisc`, [here is the documentation](https://rdrr.io/cran/Hmisc/man/wtd.stats.html). The source code uses a similar approach which I really briefly put in my comment. I wanted to use the weights as the number of observations for each std, e.g. std_1 is from 10 observations, std_2 is from 20, i wanted to calculate `wtd.var(c(std_1^2, std_2^2), c(10, 20))`.

Comment: The reason why I chose that method is because I found [a thread here](https://socratic.org/statistics/random-variables/addition-rules-for-variances) during my Google searching that told you could sum the variances. I found a couple more pages like that, but I think it's just something different then.

Comment: It is true [if you have independent normal distributions that you sum together](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables). You data isn't normal (you're using `sample` so you have a discrete uniform distribution), and you are combining the data, not summing it. So it's very far from applying in this case.